# CW structure on $SO(n)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, topological-groups, cw-complexes

Surprisingly I didn’t find such a question. I want to construct a cellular (CW) structure on SO(n) groups. I can do it for $n = 2$ and $n= 3$ because those are homeomorphic to the circle and projective space respectively. But there is no obvious way to generalize it.

I suppose it can be done somehow using action on sphere.

Comment: One way is to use the fibration $SO(n+1)/SO(n)\cong S^{n+1}$, to construct the CW structure inductively.

Comment: I thought about it but I don’t know how to use it.

Comment: I don’t know what it is.

Comment: Are you familiar with the CW structure on the product of CW-complexes? The construction for fiber bundles is more or less the same, with the added step of choosing a trivialization above each cell.

Comment: This is also in Hatcher, section 3.D.